# Need advice on doing PHP unit test on complex methods within a class

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I am a beginner of unit testing and having difficulty of testing an algorithm (which is executable by cron in actual implementation) that is within a PHP class with functions that don't have arguments as well as depending on other classes for data sources, e.g. this one:

```
class Mailing_System_Algo {     

    function __construct()
    {

        //Run the mailing system method    

        $this->execute_mailing_system();

    }

    function execute_mailing_system()
    {           

        $Class_Data_Source = new Data_Source;
        $groups = $Class_Data_Source->get_groups();

        //Proceed only if groups are defined
        if (!(empty($groups))) {
            //rest of the algo codes here-very long and lots of loops and if statements

        }
    }   

}
```

I would like treat the algo function like a blackbox so I won't be altering anything on their codes when I do the test. But how can I start testing them by feeding them inputs if the execute_mailing_system will run right away the moment the class is instantiated?

Supposing I would like to check if the algo will execute with or without groups, how can I provide an input in my unit test codes for $groups?

This is how my test case would look like:

```
class WP_Test_Mailing_System_Algo extends WP_UnitTestCase {

/**
 * Run a simple test to ensure that the tests are running
 */


function test_tests() {
            //no problem here
    $this->assertTrue( true );
}

function test_if_algo_wont_run_if_no_groups_provided {

            //Instantiate, but won't this algo run the construct function rightaway?
    $Mailing_System_Algo = new Mailing_System_Algo;

            //rest of the test codes here
            //how can I access or do detailed testing of execute_mailing_system() function and test if it won't run if groups are null or empty.
            //The function does not have any arguments

}
```

}

Of course there are lots of tests that I would be writing but I'm currently stuck on this one. This is the first test that I would need to execute. But I have a problem on how to get started doing this. I believe that once I get the technique right, the rest of the tests would be straightforward. I would appreciate any of your inputs and help..Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is two flaws with the code that will hamper testing:

1. [Constructor does Real Work](http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/flaw-constructor-does-real-work/)
2. [Hard-Coded Dependencies](http://sebastian-bergmann.de/archives/885-Stubbing-Hard-Coded-Dependencies.html)

You can improve this by changing the class to

```
class Mailing_System_Algo 
{     
    public function __construct()
    {
        // constructors should not do work
    }

    public function execute_mailing_system(Data_Source $Class_Data_Source)
    {           
        $groups = $Class_Data_Source->get_groups();

        //Proceed only if groups are defined
        if (!(empty($groups))) {
            //rest of the algo codes here-very long and lots of loops and if statements
        }
    }   
}
```

This is way, you can replace your `Data_Source` with a [Mock or Stub](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html), returning defined test values.

If this is not an option, have a look at the Test Helper extension:

- https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-test-helpers¹

In particular, have a look at `set_new_overload()`, which can be used to register a callback that is automatically invoked when the new operator is executed.

---

¹ [the Test-Helper extension is superseded](https://twitter.com/s_bergmann/status/457816903881588736) by https://github.com/krakjoe/uopz